# Unexpected token { in Jest testing

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I'm starting to learn Jest testing framework, and trying to do simple test by using `npm test`, but I have this error:

[image]

I am trying to change `import` to `require`, but it did not help :( any suggestions about how can I handle this error?

Also here is my `package.json` file part, that related to

```
devDependencies and jest:
{
    "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "jest": "^22.4.3",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "testURL": "http://localhost:1234/"
  }
}
```